# Is there a better way to do this layout ? Maybe using Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Is there an easier (better) way to do this layout? Maybe with ConstraintLayout?

The 3333 has to be always at the bottom right corner, and the 2222 under the 1111.

Not sure if there is a better way to use a single RelativeLayout or FrameLayout?

I have tried the Constraint Layout but Android Studio gets a bit crazy when moving the elements.

[image: ScreenShot layout]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LeftLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="222222222"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3333"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/LeftLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />       
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ConstraintLayout, you could create the text view containing the "111" with its width set to `MATCH_CONSTRAINT` (0dp), height set to maxLines and `WRAP_CONTENT`. Then constraint it to left and top of parent, and on the right constrained to the view containing the "3333". The view with "222" is simply constrained to the bottom of "111" vertically, and to the left of parent. "333" then simply gets constrained to bottom and right of parent.

[image: like this]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
        android:maxLines="2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2222222222"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3333"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LinearLayout with weights for these kind of scenarios.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="11111111111111111111111111111111111111111" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="2222222222" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom" 
        android:text="3333" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So there are in total only 3 TextView (not 4), also the 3333 needs to be at the right bottom corner. So you need to add  android:gravity="bottom" and    android:layout_height="match_parent" to the 3333 textview. My question is more if Constraint Layout offers something simpler.

Comment: yes, you are right, this seems to be the recommended one, i learnt it from the Android Nanodegree program.